# Cant read input line in C

Tags: c

Sorry for a stupid question, but this is really starting to annoy me.

I need to take a line of input from a console. Here's the relavent fragment of code:

```
int number_read=0;
char line[80];

printf("Enter register address: ");
number_read = scanf("%s\n", line);
printf("number of characters entered: %d; characters entered: %s.\n", number_read, line);
if (number_read > 0) {
  <read some registers and display the results.>
}
```

It doesn't work. The "Enter register address" line is printed, and the cursor stops at the end of the line, and moves to the next line when I press enter, but then nothing else happens. I've tried replacing scanf() with fscanf(stdin,...), with fgets(stdin), gets, GNU's getline(), a short function that does the same thing, with diagnostics:

```
char *new_line, ch;
for(;;) {
  ch = fgetc(stdin);
  if(ch == EOF) break;
  if((*line++ = ch) == '\n') break;
  printf("Line so far: %s\n", line);
}
*line='\0';
```

I get the same response from all of them. I'm including all the requisite headers.

I'm on a Windows XP box, compiling with gcc 3.4.5 (mingw).

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: remove '\n' from scanf it will work

Comment: A compilable example might be helpful, chances are that the problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: Thanks user2760375, but it makes no difference.

Comment: You're right, rmartinjak; it's not there. The posted code compiles (with appropriate includes), and works properly (with the '\n' removed from the scanf()). That's at least given me somewhere to start. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `scanf()` returns the number of fields it read, not the number of characters in the string (which is one field).

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. It does, too. Should have read the documentation a bit harder.

Comment: `stdin` + `EOF`? I think it'd be better to use `feof(stdio)` in this case

Comment: Is your intention to find the length of the input string inclusive to the operation of `scanf()` ? I.e to avoid a `strlen` call ? If so you can use a `%n` additional format specifier  and provide an additional input argument address (of an `int` var) to retrieve it. note: the additional argument does NOT count in the parsed-arg result, so your result will still be `1` on success, with your arg containing the number of chars processed. If you want to read an entire line, I highly advise `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Comment: WhozCraig, no; I just need to know that it's read some stuff successfully. Thanks Elias; that routine was to try to figure out why it wasn't reading what I typed. It's no longer in use.

Answer (score 0):

In scanf you should use a %i to represent a int so, try with

```
 scanf("%I", number_line);
```

Comment: Thanks Antonio, but I want the input to be a char * (actually, an array of chars), not an int.

Comment: number_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, (void *)line,sizeof line); it will work but only in linux

Comment: `%d` and `%i` are completely equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will works,

```
char buff_msg[1024];
while(1)
{
    if(fgets(buff_msg,1024, stdin) != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", buff_msg);

        memset(buff_msg, 0, 1024); // you will need this line
    }

}
```

You can
    break the loop on your own condition

Answer (score 0):

try read() it works in MinGW replace

this

```
number_read = scanf("%s\n", line);
```

with this also include `#include<unistd.h>`

```
number_read = read(STDIN_FILENO, (void *)line,sizeof line);
```

Answer (score 0):

value scanf returns is not the number of strings in the number of elements to read(this case meybe 1).

Use the `%n` To get the number, such as desired.

```
scanf("%s%n", line, &number_read);
printf("number of characters entered: %d; characters entered: %s.\n", number_read, line);
```